# Different assets in targets - phonegap

Tags: xcode, cordova

I've created 2 targets, and 2 sibling folders (with different names) next to www folder. I linked each folder to the coresponding target. Now how can I order the index.html that is in www folder, to access the correct folder and asset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to share my solution inorder for the others to know. After creating two target using [this guide](http://xperienced.com.pl/blog/building-lite-version-in-5-easy-steps), than I creates a index2.html, and place it next to the original index.html. This one will server the free version. In AppDelegate.m I've used the `#ifdef` form the guide to determine if this is the free version, and changed it to index2.html file. Works perfect.